# weights & biases : ERROR Failed to sample metric: Not Supported

Tags: python, tensorboard, yolo, wandb

I am training a yolox model and using wandb (weight & biases library) to follow training evolution. My problem is that when I am loading wandb library (version 0.13.5) I get an error message, which is:
wandb: ERROR Failed to sample metric: Not Supported

The surprising thing is that when I run the exact same code on google collab (that has the library version), it works perfectly (problem: can't have unlimited GPU access on collab). So I have to find out how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

Engineer from W&B here! Would it be possible if you could share the console log so that we can find the line where the error originates.